# Ternary operator behaviour inconsistency

Tags: c#, casting, int, conditional-operator, short

Following expression is ok

```
short d = ("obj" == "obj" ) ? 1 : 2;
```

But when you use it like below, syntax error occurs

```
short d = (DateTime.Now == DateTime.Now) ? 1 : 2;
```

Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Can anyone explain why this is so?

Is there a difference between comparing string-to-string and datetime-to-datetime in a ternary operator, why?

I would be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: from [tag:ternary-operator]: "A ternary operator is **any** operator that takes three arguments. For the ternary conditional operator `?`...`:`, use `tag:conditional-operator`" (My emphasis)

Comment: a tailor-made question for [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)

Comment: TRWTF is that `d` usually will be equal to `2` in the second case.

Comment: @Joker_vD: Are you sure? DateTime implements a true equality operator (i.e., not identity equality) and DateTime.Now has a resolution of about 10ms. I'd be surprised if you managed to get that statement to evaluate to false in anything but the raciest of conditions.

Comment: @Phoshi Well, on my home machine it's indeed is equal to `1` consistently. However, on the computer I use at work, the result is fifty-fifty: sommetimes it's `1`, sometimes is `2`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[C# language specification, version 5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), section 6.1.9:

> An implicit constant expression conversion permits the following conversions:
>
> - A constant-expression (§7.19) of type int can be converted to type sbyte, byte, short, ushort, uint, or ulong, provided the value of the constant-expression is within the range of the destination type.

Your first example *is* a constant expression, because it can be evaluated at compile time. But see section 7.19 for more details:

> Only the following constructs are permitted in constant expressions:
>
> - Literals (including the null literal).

[...]

> - The predefined +, –, *, /, %, <<, >>, &, |, ^, &&, ||, ==, !=, <, >, <=, and >= binary operators, provided each operand is of a type listed above.
> - The ?: conditional operator.

Comment: This is the right answer, +1

Comment: Spot on. The kind of answer we should see more of on SO!

Comment: I may sound to rigorous, but string literals realy shouldn't be treated as constant expressions. Why is `System.String` special?

Comment: @Joker_vD - care to explain your reasoning? Why should string *literals* be treated any differently from any other literals?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Because `System.String` is a reference type. All literals are value types, *except* strings. Why am I disallowed to have, say, `Point { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 }` literal? To have `DateTime { totalMilliseconds: 12 }` literal?

Comment: @Joker_vD Isn't your own example convincing enough that whether the type is a value type is irrelevant?

Comment: @Joker_vD - so your complaint is more along the lines that there are string literals but no means to create new types of literals?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever "Either any of the reference types shouldn't have literals, or either all value types should have literals". Right now, `string` is so more equal than other types that it ticks me off. That's why I said that it "may sound too rigorous".

Comment: @Joker_vD: If your question "why is string special?" is not rhetorical then the answer is: strings are special for the same reason that "32 bit int" is special: because it is **highly pragmatic** to put support for these commonly used data types directly into the language.  C# was not designed to be democratic/agnostic/bring-balance-to-the-Force/whatever with respect to its treatment of data types. The data types that in practice people use in LOB applications are special because it is pragmatic to make them special.

Answer (score 17):

I believe in the first case the compiler knows that the strings are equal at compile time and therefore optimizes the code to just:

`short d = 1;`

That works because `1` can be assigned to `short` variable.

In the second case optimization cannot happen because compiler cannot infer equality at compile time, so it leaves:

`short d = (DateTime.Now == DateTime.Now) ? (long)1 : (long)2;`

This will compile:

`short d = (DateTime.Now == DateTime.Now) ? (short)1 : (short)2;`

IL (LinqPad) for call **short d = ("obj" == "obj" ) ? 1 : 2;**:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // d
```

Comment: We need prove :) Some IL code maybe?

Comment: 1 shouldn't be treated as short but as int, unless you explicitly cast it.

Comment: My proof is 'code unreachable' flagged by R# in the first case (`2` is unreachable)

Comment: @ken2k Like I commented on the now deleted (and edited and undeleted) answer, C# allows an implicit conversion from `int` to `short` if the value is constant and fits in `short`.

Comment: If the code were: **`short d = (DateTime.Now == DateTime.Now) ? 1 : 1;`**, would this successfully compile to **`short d = 1;`**?

Comment: @kevin i don't know of top of my head. Just type it in VS and see for yourself.

Answer (score 4):

"obj" == "obj" can be resolved at compile time; compiler treats it as

short d = 1;

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      short d = ("obj" == "obj") ? 1 : 2;
    }
  }
}

.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
 // Code size       4 (0x4)
 .maxstack  1
 .locals init ([0] int16 d)
 IL_0000:  nop
 IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1
 IL_0002:  stloc.0
 IL_0003:  ret
 } // end of method Program::Main
```

DateTime.Now == DateTime.Now can't be resolved at compile time and throws an error.

Comment: That's obvious, and it does not explain error

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy On the contrary? It explains why there is no error in the first case—even though obviously it should be a compile error.

Comment: @Joker_vD No, it explains why there is no error in the first case, and why there shouldn't be one.

Comment: @Joker_vD why compiler treats ternary operator differently?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy C# allows an implicit conversion from `int` to `short` if the value is constant and fits in `short`. In the first case, the value is constant. In the second case, the value is not constant. In other words, the fact that `"obj" == "obj"` can be resolved at compile time is why `("obj" == "obj" ) ? 1 : 2` can be resolved at compile time, which is why it is valid for initialising a `short`.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy is right, it obviously explains the difference between the two cases, but it doesn't explain why the **result** is different.

Comment: I want a simple explanation for the answer. I couldn't understand the IL code

Comment: @ken2k: Yes, it does. C# allows implicit int->short only for values known at compile-time. "obj"=="obj" is known at compile-time so the entire expression can be optimised out, however DateTime.Now==DateTime.Now is not constant nor known at compiletime therefore the assignment is done at runtime therefore it is illegal to implicitly convert it. The C# compiler could probably look down both paths and see there are constant values that are both safely castable, but it does not.